# Example of $[K(s):F(s)]$ is not a divisor of $[K:F]$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

It should be possible that $[K(s):F(s)]$ is not a divisor of $[K:F]$ for $K$, $F$ subfields of $\mathbb{C}$, and $s$ algebraic. But I can't think of an example.

Comment: Why  do you think it should be possible?

Comment: Just by thinking the corresponding Galois groups, I can come up with groups with this property, but i cant come up with subgroups that correspond to the required extension. Well maybe it is not possible after all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Consider, for instance, any cubic polynomial $f\in \Bbb Q[x]$ with splitting field of degree $6$ over $\Bbb Q$ ($x^3 -2$ springs to mind as an example). Let $a,b\in \Bbb C$ be two roots of that polynomial. Then
$$
[\Bbb Q(a): \Bbb Q] = [\Bbb Q(b):\Bbb Q] = 3\\
[\Bbb Q(a, b): \Bbb Q(a)] = [\Bbb Q(a, b): \Bbb Q(b)]= 2
$$
As $2\nmid 3$, this is an example of what you're looking for.